# Possibilities of a uml component diagram

Tags: uml

I have a question concerning the uml component diagram: as I can see in [Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Policy_Admin_Component_Diagram.PNG), it is possible to create my own "component types" like `<<thin client>>`, `<<thick client>>` etc. I thought that I can only say `<<subsystem>>` and `<<component>>`?! Are these entries stereotypes or what? I'd like to model a third-party-database like oracle or mysql. Do I have to create something like `<<database>>` or should I use the artifact for this?

To make it more clear I added a graphic example: the "Zugriffsmanagement" (access management) uses the artifact "Drittanbieter-Datenbank" (Third-Party-Database) to store the data. Should it be `<<artifact>>` or `<<database>>` or what? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The stereotypes are for that.

You DO CAN use a stereotype that says something different that "<<subsystem>>" and "<<component>>". Of course, your "thin client" or "database", its an specialization of a "component".

```
    +-------------------+
    |  <<thin client>>  |<--------+
    |  Local Database 1 |         |
    +-------------------+         |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
    +-------------------+         |+--------------------+
    |  <<thin client>>  |<--------+|  <<system>>        |
    |  Local Database 2 |         ||  Finantial Server  |
    +-------------------+         |+--------------------+
                                  |
                                  |
    +-------------------+         |
    |  <<database>>     |<--------+
    |  North SQL Server |         |
    +-------------------+         |
                                  |
                                  |
    +-------------------+         |
    |  <<database>>     |<--------+
    |  Sth SQL Server   |
    +-------------------+
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you mark the strings in < > as code so I can see it, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

In UML you have stereotypes but also keywords. It means that you can write whatever you want  with keywords and only what is available into the profile with stereotypes.

My answer is therefore yes to "thin client" using keyword approach.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer! How would you model the database thing?

Comment: There are almost as many ways of modelling something as there are modelling tools out there. Which tool are you using?

Comment: I use Papurus for private use home and Omondo in my company. The keywords feature is available in Rational IBM and Omondo. I did not find this feature in the other tools but don't have try to all of them.

Comment: Hi Strauberry. You can make another post with the first draft of your component diagram and we will have a look.

Comment: Just replace artifact by database. If you can not do it then this is a tool limitation. The best is to change your UML tool.